# Is there a way to specify a default base-template for all templates in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm 2 hours into Django and am wondering if there is a way to specify a default base template that will automatically be loaded for all templates so that you don't have to repeat yourself and specify `{% extends "foo.html" %}` at the top of every page template.

For example, at the project or app level some metadata(settings) could specify a default template that was used unless either the call to render or the template itself specified that you shouldn't include the template. 
i. e. `render(... other args..., layout=null)` or `{% noextends "foo.html" %}`

This effectively turns the opt-in style into an opt-out, which in my experience is preferred. Given that it's specified in something like settings it's not "magic" and breaking with the spirit of Django.

I've looked over the documentation and this doesn't seem to be available by default.  I suppose I could do something like override the built-in render routine to try and concatenate the `{% extends "foo.html" %}` call on to every template, but I am hoping the internet can just tell me there is already a solution that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to write your own template loader function that looks to your settings for the default and monkey-patch it in, then "no, there isn't a way to do that" is accurate.

At least it's only one line per file.

Plus, being a long-standing Django convention, other devs will immediately be able to see which base template is used (in more complex projects you may find you use different base templates depending on, say, the type of user).

Finally, as the Zen of Python goes, explicit is better than implicit. :-)

Comment: Yea, in one of my past projects I had a default and then different base per controller, so in this case something like a different one per "app".

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget, it's a guiding principle in Python - and therefore also in Django - that explicit is better than implicit. So whereas Rails, for example, emphasises convention over configuration and has all sorts of things happen automatically, this is very much alien to the Python way of doing things.

So no, there is no way to get Django to make templates inherit from a base automatically. And while you probably could get that working by creating a custom template loader, it's not a very good idea as it would confuse everyone else looking at your project.

Comment: I get that, which is why I included the line about magic in my question. I'd consider the default template/static dirs more "magic" than something like this where it's theoretically specified in settings or as some constant at the top of some file that everything lasses through (like views.py).  Thanks a lot for your input Daniel.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try

```
{% include "foo.html" %}
```

Comment: So, {% extends "foo.html" %} is a way of rendering this template using a base template, but you have to specify that at the top of every template.  I'm asking if there is a way to tell djengo, like in settings.py, "pretend I put an extends line at the top of every template by default unless I specify otherwise in the template file or render call".  I'm not terribly familiar with django yet, but include seems like a counterpart to extends and doesn't solve the larger architectural "problem".

Comment: FYI, I have not voted on this. I find "no there isn't any" a reasonable answer as long as it's accurate.